# Python - extract package into conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I want to install a package in a conda enviroment, and not system-wise.

the package, however, can't be installed via `conda install`, neither via conda's `pip install`.

documentation -> [Bregman Toobox](http://digitalmusics.dartmouth.edu/~mcasey/bregman/)<- says it must be extracted and installed like so:

```
cd /path/to/installer/directory sudo python setup.py install
```

how do I install this into my conda enviroment?

Comment: What happens when you try to pip install it? It's got a perfectly valid setup file...  `pip install -e /path/to/installer/directory/`

Comment: this worked. I had not used `-e` flag..rookie mistake. if i `source activate myenv` and pip install it like that is it installed inside conda env?

Comment: Yes installing while inside your conda env should make the package available in that conda env, you actually don't need the `-e` flag at all, it's just so that any changes you make locally won't require you to reinstall it.  It's nice to be able to hack around sometimes if you have to bring the entire package down locally anyway.